# How to Connect Relational Database in Glue ETL / Spark using ODBC connector

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, odbc, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I need to Ingest data from RDBMS using ODBC Connector in AWS ecosystem. AWS Glue does not provide ODBC Connection. How can I connect my spark code with Relational DB using ODBC driver in spark.

I tried sqoop with EMR. But it also does not provides ODBC connection. Then I tried with spark. But I am still not able to find a solution regarding this.

Need to connect relational database in spark using ODBC Driver

Answer (score 0):

I have used pymysql as a zip file, added it to my AWS Glue job.  Then I have imported the pymysql library in my AWS Glue.  Hope you can follow similar for your respective RDBMS as well.  Since the information is not fully available, am assuming you would like to read/write to an rdbms.  Here is the sample code snipped I have for connecting to my AWS RDS.

```
import pymysql

rds_host  = "rds.url.aaa.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
name = "username"
password = "userpwd"
db_name = "dbname"
conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)

with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("select * from your table query)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    for row in result:
       print("Column1 value=>: ", row[0])
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
```

Let me know if you need any further directions, if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well can you please explain the reason for down voting? Thanks